# How to run command in the background and notify me via email when done

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following command which will take ages to run (couple of hours). I would like to make it a background process and for it to send me an email when its done.

For the cherry on the top,  any errors it encountered should write to a text file when an error has occurred?

```
find . -type f -name "*.rm" -exec ./rm2mp3.sh \{} \; -exec rm \{} \;
```

How can I do this with my above command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
yourcommand 2>&1 | mail -s "yourcommand is done" yourname@example.com
```

The `2>&1` bit says "make my errors like the regular output", and the rest says "take the regular output and mail it to me with a nice subject line"

Note that it doesn't work in `csh` family of shells, only Bourne (`sh`, `bash`, `ksh`...), AFAIK. Thus, run under `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`.  (N.B. You can pipe both descriptors in `csh` using `yourcommand |& mail ...`, but only a madman writes scripts using `csh`.)

**UPDATE:**

> How would I write the errors to a log file and then just email my self on completion?

if you mean just email the fact that it is done,

```
yourcommand 1>/dev/null 2>mylogfile ; (echo "done!" | mail -s "yourcommand is done")
```

if you mean just email the errors (in which case you don't need the log file) (**fixed as @Trey** said),

```
yourcommand 2&>1 1>/dev/null | mail -s "yourcommand is done" yourname@example.com
```

Comment: The problem with this is that regular output will also come through and not just errors, right?

Comment: How would I write the errors to a log file and then just email my self on completion?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the explanation. One final question, does the write command which contains the write to log file run in the background? I ask because I tried it and closed my shell and it just stopped processing my files?? Shall I use a `&` at end?

Comment: I think the redirections should actually be swapped on that last command to redirect stderr through to stdout and close stdout: `yourcommand 2>&1 1>/dev/null`

Comment: @Abs: Yes, run your command like this: `nohup yourcommand ... mail ... &`

Comment: @Dennis. I try to just close my shell (SSH connection using Putty) when I run the command. But it runs the job in the background and finishes but it doesn't send the email when I tried the `nohup` and `$`.

Comment: @Abs: Sorry, you'll need to put your commands in a script in order to use `nohup` since it doesn't work with command sequences or pipelines. Then you can do `nohup scriptname &`